# Change transparency of columns/stack columns on top of each other in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created the upper graph in the picture using `geom_col` in ggplot. As you can see the red graph covers the blue graph sometimes and I don't want that.

To solve this I would like to make the red columns more transparent. Alternatively, I would like to design the columns so that if the red column is larger than the blue one (i.e. if the snow height is larger than the precipitation), the column is blue up to the precipitation point and only the tip is red.

I tried using the `position = "stack"` argument but unfortunately it didn't work. Unfortunately there also does not seem to be an `alpha` argument to change the transparency.

Is there a way to solve this?

I'd really appreciate some help!

Here is the code for the graph:

```
plot <- ggplot(dfQ1, aes(x = Date)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = Precipitation, color = "Precipitation")) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = Snowdepth, color = "Snowdepth")) + 
  labs(x = "Month-Year", 
       y = "Precipitation [mm] and snowdepth [cm]", 
       color = "Legend") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = PS_color, labels = c("Precipitation", "Snow depth")) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 month", date_labels = "%m-%Y", expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
   deforestation_period +
   theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
         axis.line = element_line(), 
         legend.title.align = 0.5)
```

[image]

Here is the dataframe that I used to create the upper graph:

```
df <- structure(list(Discharge = c(9.99744004987013, 12.537803145974, 
12.3166566233766, 10.4546782753247, 16.1048035823377, 16.9084997485714, 
16.1584768332468, 14.5327760041558, 12.2191523158442, 9.99138980571428, 
8.21859196675325, 7.11745852675325, 6.15944567688312, 5.3760772987013, 
4.80059809246753, 4.27617724675325, 3.87007278545455, 3.56369793662338, 
6.66835671272727, 6.38664109714286, 9.24151545350649, 10.1183654898701, 
9.40309804051948, 7.99023340051948, 6.85123544103896, 6.0739330161039, 
5.31220166649351, 4.74078662649351, 4.28195033766234, 3.91874336415584, 
3.58792113038961, 3.17473972363636, 2.8052322825974, 2.78720969142857, 
2.0472821801093, 3.4457538107146, 1.34182790649351, 1.18155298909091, 
1.06364055272727, 1.08481259220779, 1.12340130077922, 0.971319347532468, 
0.843713953246753, 0.869419636363636, 0.925078291948052, 1.12260327896104, 
1.07624350753247, 1.26964149194805, 1.56406464, 1.62277736727273, 
1.00358963532468, 0.927496594285714, 0.917780745974026, 1.16367200415584, 
1.58244876467532, 1.66162819324675, 1.52536866077922, 1.66903794701299, 
1.92796505766234, 2.10447150545455, 2.15782765714286, 2.19523032935065, 
2.24288565194805, 2.38870843012987, 2.49395507532468, 2.29273171948052, 
2.2600368374026, 2.59585501090909, 2.34588701922078, 2.33441063064935, 
2.30906513454545, 2.25261272103896, 2.23271783064935, 2.1732638587013, 
2.05828161662338, 1.93873745454545, 1.86066753662338, 1.87353687272727, 
1.74183611844156, 1.61582048415584, 1.51604374441558, 1.41118488935065, 
1.30974388363636, 1.21889013194805, 1.13077312831169, 1.02645062649351, 
0.95062464, 0.893832461298701, 0.837987091948052, 0.848149302857143, 
0.884282456103896, 0.82290254961039, 0.747830823896104, 0.674176507012987, 
0.671900708571429, 0.64164297974026, 0.594519746493507, 0.576154921558442, 
0.539186942337662, 0.747937645714286, 0.949014682597403, 0.801450215064935, 
0.611933273766234, 0.552449903376623, 0.570622404155844, 0.658775314285714, 
0.507596633766234, 0.446735576103896, 0.458253481558442, 0.522027902337662, 
0.459369275844156, 0.663480635844156, 0.681931636363636, 0.563703447272727, 
0.727006852987013, 0.748770227532468, 1.43766794805195, 0.899341190649351, 
1.42979657142857, 0.999710163116883, 0.936061415064935, 0.911697063896104, 
1.05979496727273, 1.05887508779221, 0.917776706493506, 1.55410821818182, 
1.55226778597403, 1.26333429194805, 1.08772819948052, 1.70330441142857, 
1.86780440103896, 1.57228094337662, 1.59869847272727, 1.54107775168831, 
1.45496836987013, 1.47059083636364, 1.60137260883117, 1.35620172467532, 
1.25087316779221, 1.17084769246753, 1.28120315844156, 1.30683119376623, 
1.06993069714286, 0.929166470649351, 0.836211515844156, 0.758486749090909, 
0.685071434805195, 0.633646603636364, 0.614798836363636, 0.896476525714286, 
1.00614729974026, 0.734582674285714, 0.716790557922078, 0.633727842077922, 
0.715979071168831, 0.976618248311689, 0.932930368831169, 1.12156760103896, 
0.857088897662338, 0.723439767272727, 0.634314688831169, 0.542486524675325, 
0.730394406233766, 0.766583214545454, 1.08667501714286, 0.870913346493507, 
0.83538633974026, 1.0898222212987, 0.954876193246753, 0.783505720519481, 
0.779755062857143, 1.1924021361039, 1.14196248935065, 1.15806408311688, 
0.878188226493506, 1.24856258493507, 1.35089115428571, 1.05372834077922, 
1.00294242077922, 0.942283112727273, 1.21455778909091, 1.08321811948052, 
0.897879347532468, 0.79430212987013, 0.729110075844156, 0.669889047272727, 
0.646307906493506, 0.690424644155844, 0.582499598961039, 0.680649774545455, 
0.582474464415584, 0.511617487792208, 0.528933618701299, 0.525628874805195, 
1.3579761787013, 2.39924496623377, 1.70024158753247, 1.48713250909091, 
2.04766316883117, 1.77936648311688, 1.64474877506493, 1.59984568519481, 
1.51589989402597, 1.36808116363636, 1.19996337038961, 1.0737691012987, 
0.981578954805195, 0.899445992727273, 0.91084046961039, 1.8455515761039, 
1.51085480727273, 1.15529748779221, 0.925469448311688, 0.815691628051948, 
0.768636168311688, 0.717068384415584, 0.646048706493507, 1.33895359168831, 
1.93757700155844, 1.06518251220779, 0.953629115844156, 0.906931598961039, 
0.834939528311688, 0.756594925714286, 0.692241961558442, 0.630866094545455, 
0.593780297142857, 0.537725772467533, 0.485478907012987, 0.430025367272727, 
0.382827852467533, 0.346770551688312, 0.350987769350649, 0.339612143376623, 
0.298872635844156, 0.266988791688312, 0.282857442077922, 0.293789622857143, 
0.622183231168831, 0.553096669090909, 0.339906576623377, 0.292085635324675, 
0.261629971948052, 0.658852513246753, 0.527037082597403, 0.361696881038961, 
0.324538597402597, 0.291182811428571, 0.262071172987013, 0.228150084155844, 
0.280437793246753, 0.285945176103896, 0.406582242077922, 0.387907723636364, 
0.35496374025974, 0.402543883636364, 0.405658996363636, 0.313854171428571, 
0.264386468571429, 0.403830009350649, 0.388069078441558, 0.392660845714286, 
0.367899278961039, 0.344315220779221, 0.325821132467532, 0.337982661818182, 
0.319252937142857, 0.337200573506494, 0.343875141818182, 0.330466535064935, 
0.33739401974026, 0.257833309090909, 0.293736660779221, 0.421110907012987, 
0.381522427012987, 0.382058331428571, 1.11054206337662, 3.01473118753247, 
1.37216216103896, 1.79399680831169, 2.77628222337662, 1.94178681350649, 
2.18481093818182, 1.84594520103896, 1.68107829194805, 1.77990912, 
1.96343057454545, 1.9992728851948, 2.25769506077922, 1.92386700467532, 
1.96211549922078, 1.88091767688312, 1.72540889766234, 1.63910988467532, 
1.57609645714286, 1.45808999064935, 1.31543506285714, 1.23646972675325, 
1.22714391272727, 2.09385777038961, 1.7294313225974, 1.30846112415584, 
1.22250120311688, 2.20468720207792, 1.57262385038961, 1.78482157714286, 
2.02835243220779, 2.70067504207792, 2.81894497246753, 3.10211098597403, 
3.18524057766234, 3.45388622961039, 3.14291063688312, 2.9874326025974, 
2.94674560831169, 2.83196937974026, 2.60824836155844, 2.44497435428571, 
2.32265260051948, 2.21460681974026, 2.10928073142857, 1.97574380883117, 
1.94208753038961, 1.86264957506494, 1.75188410181818, 1.64165430857143, 
1.54992084779221, 1.59483493402597, 1.79811887376623, 1.49538628987013, 
1.52355583168831, 1.48430016, 1.31028292987013, 1.27068704415584, 
1.21735288519481, 1.15405400103896, 1.15302034285714, 1.18979532467532, 
1.69452706909091, 1.39339367064935, 1.22202678857143, 1.17903302649351, 
1.11074987220779, 1.17333107532468, 1.47353337350649, 1.28187752727273, 
1.22529270857143, 1.20350419948052, 2.20558351792208, 3.71077968623377, 
6.16877059324675, 8.91325514805195, 9.65918472311688, 9.01428345350649, 
7.88626323116883, 7.03825598337662, 6.91994655584415, 12.4629165631169, 
14.4401596924675, 13.2966837444156, 12.4676102150649, 12.6402697309091, 
12.419136, 11.2089116758442, 9.61021342753247, 8.05331437714286, 
7.63696332467533, 6.38924005402597, 5.93472937558442, 5.59342985142857, 
5.2159823625974, 4.84172539012987, 4.53829913766234, 4.25536741402597, 
4.10020086857143, 3.82536561038961, 3.49439234493507, 3.18972776727273, 
2.94382596155844, 2.71426879168831, 2.55884125090909, 2.42166071688312, 
2.24444893090909, 2.1223008748052, 1.99254715012987, 1.86006453194805, 
1.76520541090909, 1.67413285402597, 1.59043953038961, 1.48302705038961, 
1.34392282597403, 1.22767106493506, 1.20382264519481, 1.29860030337662, 
5.74401854337662, 8.56775882805195, 10.8728132072727, 10.103572238961, 
8.29773032727273, 7.36322433662338, 8.14247536207792, 7.27382906181818, 
7.04602973922078, 6.42328479584415, 5.75393771220779, 5.15400887688312, 
4.64796991168831, 4.19445720935065, 3.77439522077922, 3.43259480103896, 
3.1745231625974, 3.01173860571429, 3.15159933506493, 2.84777945766234, 
2.5747271812987, 2.36823791376623, 2.21376974961039, 2.06157828155844, 
1.95880155428571, 1.86929766233766, 1.79284982025974, 1.70750120727273, 
1.62175133922078, 1.54985284987013, 1.51478993454545, 1.46620755116883, 
1.4437641974026, 1.36335766441558, 1.36703336727273, 1.46826633974026, 
1.80497185246753, 2.19711654233766, 2.7281520374026, 4.3920445838961, 
5.49790242077922, 5.41509396779221, 4.9902954638961, 4.46915018805195, 
4.02145074701299, 3.6408138638961, 3.36573623688312, 3.19951228675325, 
3.03193084675325, 2.82038886233766, 2.77608698181818, 2.48114969766234, 
2.26399059116883, 2.13342493090909, 1.98106874181818, 1.8870825974026, 
1.78382943584416, 1.68159108155844, 1.61407834597403, 1.55205571324675, 
1.45465418805195, 1.3732862587013, 1.31180805818182, 1.23949372675325, 
1.18336312519481, 1.12369528519481, 1.08015664207792, 1.00130867532468, 
0.977190508051948, 1.00687126441558, 1.15149992727273, 1.88562344727273, 
2.4681917174026, 2.44156929662338, 2.83626244987013, 3.13710388363636, 
3.10446398337662, 2.95155236571429, 2.70808614233766, 2.48777085506494, 
2.31744481246753, 2.17917294545455, 2.05139542441558, 1.90356839064935, 
1.76140336207792, 1.6546147574026, 1.51741963636364, 1.64243056207792, 
1.91280129662338, 1.50541609558442, 1.32142269506493, 1.18249732987013, 
1.06416837818182, 1.00971618077922, 0.926523303896104, 0.830276621298701, 
0.750466136103896, 0.68250614025974, 0.682863634285714, 0.703936033246753, 
0.778674950649351, 0.649213190649351, 0.636549194805195, 0.970730705454545, 
0.991690447792208, 0.81116337038961, 0.700057683116883, 0.733632723116883, 
1.09670818909091, 0.96267643012987, 0.729893735064935, 0.778689986493507, 
0.733617687272727, 0.996354252467532, 1.56814451532468, 1.09708722701299, 
0.896632718961039, 0.916690759480519, 0.865702865454545, 0.766430387532468, 
1.20648309194805, 1.49983959272727, 1.62843780155844, 1.37471825454545, 
1.23166296935065, 1.17071685818182, 1.13176100571429, 1.0627271812987, 
0.979584349090909, 0.897759060779221, 0.834477456623377, 0.883843723636364, 
0.860651046233766, 0.773829818181818, 0.70376817038961, 1.01415938493506, 
1.07907473454545, 0.732217334025974, 0.617297928311688, 0.548505350649351, 
0.489581672727273, 0.439686907012987, 2.33000737246753, 2.92634017246753, 
1.70229768311688, 1.75134191376623, 1.78809378077922, 1.59691571532468, 
1.47832644155844, 1.62290842597403, 1.51681663168831, 2.27968935896104, 
1.68431952623377, 1.48416461298701, 1.41526296935065, 1.89656236051948, 
1.69478896207792, 1.45757540571429, 1.31500755116883, 1.19851117714286, 
1.10240856935065, 1.11007976727273, 1.04965564675325, 1.00563765194805, 
0.941188637922078, 0.88641777038961, 0.845485714285714, 0.831099553246753, 
0.715131004675325, 0.597059457662338, 0.55219204987013, 0.506645336103896, 
0.475455609350649, 0.436725967792208, 0.48524932987013, 1.66883529974026, 
1.34666608207792, 0.89236051948052, 0.73354161038961, 0.617604031168831, 
0.550206645194805, 0.487729795324675, 0.490119372467532, 1.10683314701299, 
0.551924097662338, 0.419206291948052, 0.425587324675325, 0.328212056103896, 
0.295995179220779, 0.302319883636364, 0.355030391688312, 0.37166990961039, 
0.299352885194805, 0.267054321038961, 0.313104847792208, 0.305024315844156, 
0.286558055064935, 0.255273849350649, 0.242141722597403, 0.261244201558442, 
0.222231796363636, 0.274652135064935, 0.365439235324675, 0.274638221298701, 
0.236580031168831, 0.228513188571429, 0.317192577662338, 0.459966894545455, 
0.265982736623377, 0.212840228571429, 0.412184328311688, 0.586305014025974, 
0.569376224415584, 0.521828621298701, 0.147076139220779, 0.137353558441558, 
0.132631181298701, 0.131902728311688, 0.273458244155844, 0.494898077922078, 
0.510203220779221, 0.562841242597403, 2.10147151792208, 0.936567472207792, 
0.615459067012987, 0.820876974545454, 1.34878568727273, 1.17915196675325, 
0.912472868571429, 0.753100775064935, 1.5871377038961, 1.05734928623377, 
2.00229823168831, 1.86075864935065, 1.47563143480519, 1.17817575896104, 
1.05129612467532, 0.964566458181818, 0.861908895584416, 0.758019067012987, 
0.721149157402598, 0.64099598961039, 0.602951264415584, 0.55203451012987, 
0.50278449038961, 0.460462404155844, 0.418803241558442, 0.390320415584416, 
0.471666801038961, 0.664625604155844, 0.510738900779221, 0.426456037402597, 
0.382992573506494, 0.433120282597403, 0.759734275324675, 1.17699219116883, 
0.894782412467532, 0.915852342857143, 0.955979869090909, 1.9360886774026, 
1.37401762909091, 1.33932118441558, 1.45587141818182, 0.943894140951273, 
1.04990597668239, 1.45805952847792, 1.11667515673932, 1.72638140080208, 
2.42627195534961, 2.2650581361039, 2.61731407792208, 2.41388314597403, 
3.15908471688312, 2.60785855168831, 2.51925479064935, 2.38746449454545, 
2.50193417142857, 4.05218692987013, 5.55365779948052, 6.26024642493507, 
6.60470931116883, 7.69677030233766, 9.58629431688312, 12.7474178493506, 
12.040904851948, 10.6114729558442, 8.69835074493507, 7.73184354077922, 
6.84063696623377, 6.08562731220779, 5.69265340675325, 4.94548012051948, 
4.60322907428571, 4.36635977142857, 4.20715195012987, 4.13372294649351, 
3.73254844675325, 3.43700456727273, 3.51155250701299, 3.5292182774026, 
3.38204788363636, 3.19593869298701, 3.15815743168831, 3.23586020571429, 
3.41659688727273, 3.48278983480519, 3.15556004571429, 3.00042806025974, 
2.95395540779221, 2.95914838441558, 3.09370235844156, 2.99973977766234, 
2.96656599272727, 3.06340872311688, 2.83254971844156, 2.67497968207792, 
2.6082432, 2.44441264207792, 2.30429495688312, 2.37707113558442, 
2.45279276883117, 2.32809019012987, 2.29887823792208, 2.2495938825974, 
2.60230673454545, 2.29038006857143, 2.02304186181818, 2.45133406753247, 
2.5364448, 2.60351521246753, 4.45422722493507, 3.47732396883117, 
3.4615195012987, 4.63995490909091, 4.32626186805195, 4.19574400831169, 
4.3061039625974), Precipitation = c(23.9, 5.1, 14.5, 21.9, 19.6, 
10, 10.7, 6.4, 3.7, 0, 0, 3.9, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10.5, 36.6, 10.8, 
16.1, 4.2, 8, 0.1, 0, 2.1, 0, 0, 0.3, 4.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.4, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 2.4, 12.5, 2.8, 1.4, 1.4, 10, 4.2, 0, 
0, 2.6, 0.8, 1.7, 0.7, 1.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 5.2, 2.1, 
0, 12.6, 0.1, 0, 2.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 3.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0, 1, 1.2, 6.6, 
10.4, 5.5, 0.2, 2.3, 0, 2.1, 0, 0, 3.2, 6, 3.2, 3.2, 7.3, 7.4, 
2.7, 3.3, 14.8, 0.4, 7.3, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 8.7, 0, 18.4, 7.4, 3.9, 
0, 0.2, 3.6, 0.1, 2.2, 0, 0, 0.1, 9.5, 1.6, 1.3, 0.3, 1.6, 21.4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5.5, 0.8, 0.3, 8.8, 8.5, 4.8, 6.3, 
0.3, 9.5, 0, 0.8, 11.8, 2.8, 2.3, 0, 9, 2.8, 0, 0.3, 3.8, 4.1, 
10.4, 0, 0, 15.3, 0.1, 0, 0.8, 2.6, 5.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.8, 
3.1, 3.4, 8.2, 0.1, 0.3, 5.1, 9.6, 15.4, 11.9, 8.3, 10.1, 4.3, 
0, 0.2, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15.2, 9.6, 5, 0, 0, 2.4, 1.5, 
0.4, 0, 21.4, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 9.8, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 
0.7, 3.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7, 7.6, 6.6, 15, 0, 1.5, 0, 4.4, 23.5, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 4.3, 0.9, 0, 3.3, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.3, 0, 0.5, 0.2, 0, 13.5, 7.7, 3, 6.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.9, 42.2, 
17.1, 19.1, 21.1, 0, 7.4, 0, 0, 4.6, 3.9, 10.3, 5.7, 1, 2.2, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9.2, 10.3, 0, 0, 17.5, 1.5, 0, 11, 
4.6, 12.6, 5.4, 2.5, 6.7, 0.5, 0, 0.7, 2.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1.4, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 10.8, 0.5, 0.2, 3.9, 0.1, 0.9, 0.5, 0.1, 
6.4, 6.1, 8.6, 1.8, 4, 0.8, 6.1, 3.3, 16.6, 2.2, 0.4, 0, 0.1, 
6.7, 10, 9.6, 8.1, 0.3, 0, 5.4, 4.9, 36.9, 13.1, 0, 22.7, 14, 
14.4, 6.2, 3.3, 3.4, 6, 12, 2.4, 3, 1.1, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0.4, 
0, 0, 0.1, 0.8, 3.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 3.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 
5.5, 10.1, 34.8, 13.3, 2.8, 15.2, 4.2, 5.3, 8.9, 10.3, 4.6, 10.1, 
3.2, 0.3, 0, 1.8, 0, 0, 4.6, 2.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.9, 0.7, 
3.1, 2.5, 3.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.7, 5.3, 4.7, 1.8, 
5.1, 5.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0, 2.1, 0.6, 0.6, 2.3, 7.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 4.7, 
0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 1.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.7, 4.4, 
10.4, 6.8, 1.4, 0.5, 0, 0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
7.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.8, 3.2, 1.7, 0.3, 10.5, 
8.4, 3.3, 0.9, 1.5, 4.5, 6.1, 0, 1, 2.6, 8.3, 12, 4.5, 1.4, 3.1, 
3.2, 0, 2.8, 17, 1.2, 4.3, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 16, 0, 
0, 0, 12.8, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 1.2, 81.9, 4.3, 6.2, 5.5, 0.3, 0, 
6, 4.5, 13.8, 3.9, 0, 0, 2.5, 10.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.8, 2, 3.1, 6.1, 2, 0.6, 0, 5.2, 
22.2, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 5.2, 0.4, 9.5, 0.1, 2.4, 0, 0, 2.4, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 9.1, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.7, 3, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.7, 34.1, 2.8, 1.8, 8.7, 12.8, 6.4, 2.8, 4.2, 
14.1, 1.3, 14.6, 10.2, 3.7, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1.2, 6.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 8.6, 3, 3.9, 2.6, 0.6, 8, 5, 
1.2, 4.9, 0, 0, 4, 0, 14.1, 7.6, 0.1, 9.2, 0.1, 8.5, 6.8, 1.5, 
0, 0.4, 13.7, 14.6, 18.6, 10.7, 18.2, 13.3, 31.1, 3.7, 4.8, 4.7, 
0, 1.5, 0, 5.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 4.1, 1.4, 1.1, 0.9, 0.6, 1.8, 1.1, 
0.2, 0.1, 0.6, 7.6, 0.7, 0.1, 0, 0, 2.3, 3.6, 0.4, 4.6, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0.6, 0, 0, 4.3, 7, 0, 3.7, 6.7, 0.1, 18.6, 0, 
0.1, 7.9, 11.8, 2.3, 0, 1.5), Snowdepth = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 10, 5, 
0, 0, 4, 7, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 18, 12, 13, 
17, 23, 28, 29, 30, 33, 36, 36, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
3, 4, 7, 7, 6, 5, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 8, 15, 23, 27, 27, 25, 26, 26, 26, 24, 19, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 12, 17, 22, 30, 32, 27, 25, 25, 24, 24, 23, 20, 18, 15, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 12, 10, 10, 10, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Date = structure(c(15340, 15341, 15342, 
15343, 15344, 15345, 15346, 15347, 15348, 15349, 15350, 15351, 
15352, 15353, 15354, 15355, 15356, 15357, 15358, 15359, 15360, 
15361, 15362, 15363, 15364, 15365, 15366, 15367, 15368, 15369, 
15370, 15371, 15372, 15373, 15374, 15375, 15376, 15377, 15378, 
15379, 15380, 15381, 15382, 15383, 15384, 15385, 15386, 15387, 
15388, 15389, 15390, 15391, 15392, 15393, 15394, 15395, 15396, 
15397, 15398, 15399, 15400, 15401, 15402, 15403, 15404, 15405, 
15406, 15407, 15408, 15409, 15410, 15411, 15412, 15413, 15414, 
15415, 15416, 15417, 15418, 15419, 15420, 15421, 15422, 15423, 
15424, 15425, 15426, 15427, 15428, 15429, 15430, 15431, 15432, 
15433, 15434, 15435, 15436, 15437, 15438, 15439, 15440, 15441, 
15442, 15443, 15444, 15445, 15446, 15447, 15448, 15449, 15450, 
15451, 15452, 15453, 15454, 15455, 15456, 15457, 15458, 15459, 
15460, 15461, 15462, 15463, 15464, 15465, 15466, 15467, 15468, 
15469, 15470, 15471, 15472, 15473, 15474, 15475, 15476, 15477, 
15478, 15479, 15480, 15481, 15482, 15483, 15484, 15485, 15486, 
15487, 15488, 15489, 15490, 15491, 15492, 15493, 15494, 15495, 
15496, 15497, 15498, 15499, 15500, 15501, 15502, 15503, 15504, 
15505, 15506, 15507, 15508, 15509, 15510, 15511, 15512, 15513, 
15514, 15515, 15516, 15517, 15518, 15519, 15520, 15521, 15522, 
15523, 15524, 15525, 15526, 15527, 15528, 15529, 15530, 15531, 
15532, 15533, 15534, 15535, 15536, 15537, 15538, 15539, 15540, 
15541, 15542, 15543, 15544, 15545, 15546, 15547, 15548, 15549, 
15550, 15551, 15552, 15553, 15554, 15555, 15556, 15557, 15558, 
15559, 15560, 15561, 15562, 15563, 15564, 15565, 15566, 15567, 
15568, 15569, 15570, 15571, 15572, 15573, 15574, 15575, 15576, 
15577, 15578, 15579, 15580, 15581, 15582, 15583, 15584, 15585, 
15586, 15587, 15588, 15589, 15590, 15591, 15592, 15593, 15594, 
15595, 15596, 15597, 15598, 15599, 15600, 15601, 15602, 15603, 
15604, 15605, 15606, 15607, 15608, 15609, 15610, 15611, 15612, 
15613, 15614, 15615, 15616, 15617, 15618, 15619, 15620, 15621, 
15622, 15623, 15624, 15625, 15626, 15627, 15628, 15629, 15630, 
15631, 15632, 15633, 15634, 15635, 15636, 15637, 15638, 15639, 
15640, 15641, 15642, 15643, 15644, 15645, 15646, 15647, 15648, 
15649, 15650, 15651, 15652, 15653, 15654, 15655, 15656, 15657, 
15658, 15659, 15660, 15661, 15662, 15663, 15664, 15665, 15666, 
15667, 15668, 15669, 15670, 15671, 15672, 15673, 15674, 15675, 
15676, 15677, 15678, 15679, 15680, 15681, 15682, 15683, 15684, 
15685, 15686, 15687, 15688, 15689, 15690, 15691, 15692, 15693, 
15694, 15695, 15696, 15697, 15698, 15699, 15700, 15701, 15702, 
15703, 15704, 15705, 15706, 15707, 15708, 15709, 15710, 15711, 
15712, 15713, 15714, 15715, 15716, 15717, 15718, 15719, 15720, 
15721, 15722, 15723, 15724, 15725, 15726, 15727, 15728, 15729, 
15730, 15731, 15732, 15733, 15734, 15735, 15736, 15737, 15738, 
15739, 15740, 15741, 15742, 15743, 15744, 15745, 15746, 15747, 
15748, 15749, 15750, 15751, 15752, 15753, 15754, 15755, 15756, 
15757, 15758, 15759, 15760, 15761, 15762, 15763, 15764, 15765, 
15766, 15767, 15768, 15769, 15770, 15771, 15772, 15773, 15774, 
15775, 15776, 15777, 15778, 15779, 15780, 15781, 15782, 15783, 
15784, 15785, 15786, 15787, 15788, 15789, 15790, 15791, 15792, 
15793, 15794, 15795, 15796, 15797, 15798, 15799, 15800, 15801, 
15802, 15803, 15804, 15805, 15806, 15807, 15808, 15809, 15810, 
15811, 15812, 15813, 15814, 15815, 15816, 15817, 15818, 15819, 
15820, 15821, 15822, 15823, 15824, 15825, 15826, 15827, 15828, 
15829, 15830, 15831, 15832, 15833, 15834, 15835, 15836, 15837, 
15838, 15839, 15840, 15841, 15842, 15843, 15844, 15845, 15846, 
15847, 15848, 15849, 15850, 15851, 15852, 15853, 15854, 15855, 
15856, 15857, 15858, 15859, 15860, 15861, 15862, 15863, 15864, 
15865, 15866, 15867, 15868, 15869, 15870, 15871, 15872, 15873, 
15874, 15875, 15876, 15877, 15878, 15879, 15880, 15881, 15882, 
15883, 15884, 15885, 15886, 15887, 15888, 15889, 15890, 15891, 
15892, 15893, 15894, 15895, 15896, 15897, 15898, 15899, 15900, 
15901, 15902, 15903, 15904, 15905, 15906, 15907, 15908, 15909, 
15910, 15911, 15912, 15913, 15914, 15915, 15916, 15917, 15918, 
15919, 15920, 15921, 15922, 15923, 15924, 15925, 15926, 15927, 
15928, 15929, 15930, 15931, 15932, 15933, 15934, 15935, 15936, 
15937, 15938, 15939, 15940, 15941, 15942, 15943, 15944, 15945, 
15946, 15947, 15948, 15949, 15950, 15951, 15952, 15953, 15954, 
15955, 15956, 15957, 15958, 15959, 15960, 15961, 15962, 15963, 
15964, 15965, 15966, 15967, 15968, 15969, 15970, 15971, 15972, 
15973, 15974, 15975, 15976, 15977, 15978, 15979, 15980, 15981, 
15982, 15983, 15984, 15985, 15986, 15987, 15988, 15989, 15990, 
15991, 15992, 15993, 15994, 15995, 15996, 15997, 15998, 15999, 
16000, 16001, 16002, 16003, 16004, 16005, 16006, 16007, 16008, 
16009, 16010, 16011, 16012, 16013, 16014, 16015, 16016, 16017, 
16018, 16019, 16020, 16021, 16022, 16023, 16024, 16025, 16026, 
16027, 16028, 16029, 16030, 16031, 16032, 16033, 16034, 16035, 
16036, 16037, 16038, 16039, 16040, 16041, 16042, 16043, 16044, 
16045, 16046, 16047, 16048, 16049, 16050, 16051, 16052, 16053, 
16054, 16055, 16056, 16057, 16058, 16059, 16060, 16061, 16062, 
16063, 16064, 16065, 16066, 16067, 16068, 16069, 16070), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-731L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the reason, why `alpha` did not work is, that you used `color` instead of `fill` in `geom_col(...)`  - this might help (commenting `scale_color` and `deforestation` where shortcuts to get a working example):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = Precipitation, fill = "Precipitation"), alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = Snowdepth, fill = "Snowdepth"), alpha = 0.5) + 
  labs(x = "Month-Year", 
       y = "Precipitation [mm] and snowdepth [cm]", 
       color = "Legend") + 
 # scale_color_manual(values = PS_color, labels = c("Precipitation", "Snow depth")) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 month", date_labels = "%m-%Y", expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
#   deforestation_period +
   theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
         axis.line = element_line(), 
         legend.title.align = 0.5)
```